# Backbone error 'this.model is undefined', please explain where, how, what is 'this.model'

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, backbone.js

The answers might be on SO, but they don't really explain properly what I am about to ask.

Whenever I introduce a `this.model.toJSON()` with a template into a view, I always get this error in Firebug: `this.model is undefined`

Now, many answers in SO do not really explain what `this.model` is, they just fix the questioner's problem. So my questions are:

- How do I fix my problem?
- What is `this.model` and where does it come from or how do I define it and use it (in the error, it's undefined)?
- What is the relation between `this.model` and `Backbone.View`, `Backbone.Collection` and `Backbone.Model`?
- What is the difference between `this.model` and `this.models` (notice the 's' at the end of `model`)?
- Also, all the above questions in relation to `this.collection`?

Sorry about this question but I'm quite new to Backbone and I've made endless research online, books and in SO but no one seems to have at least made an article to explain what each of the Backbone properties and attributes are. ...Just tutorials with no in-depth explanation. Even in the Addy Osmani `Todo` tutotrial, there's no in-depth explanation of `this.model` even though it's used a lot.

Please see my code:

JS / Backbone:

```
(function($) {
    // model
    var AppModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults : {
            title : 'App Title',
            version : '0.1'
        }
    });

    // collection
    var AppList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : AppModel,
        url : '#'
    });

    // main app view
    var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : '#app',

        template : _.template($('#app-template').html()),

        initialize : function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');

            this.render();
            console.log(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        },

        render : function() {
            console.log(this.$el);
        }
    });

    var app = new AppView;
}(jQuery));
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Main App -->
    <div id="app"></div>
</div>

<!-- template with underscore.js -->
<script type="text/template" id="app-template">
    <article>
        <h2>App Name: <%= title %></h2>
        <p>Version: <%= version %></p>
    </article>
</script>
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go step by step.

**1.** How do I fix my problem?
Answer :- var app = new AppView({model : AppList});

**2.**  this.model, now you got it from the answer 1 where you will get your this.model. You need to to set the model to the view by passing it as parameter.

**3.** Model is single item. You can considered it as a single row of your DB table. Collection is the collection of models i.e. for instance multiple rows in DB

Example of user model:-

Model:- This will contain info of single user.
Collection:- This will contain info of multiple users (Each user is a instance of User Model).
View:- It will become the UI for your users. View in backbone are little confusing with there name "View". It must be called controller as they control the list of events on templates and manipulate data in collection and it's model

**4.** As said above model is a single model and this.models in collection are multiple multiple models. this.models is an array of single models.

**5.** I hope above answers will also answer you this question.

Comment: hi @pvnarula, after writing `var app = new AppView({ model: AppList });` like you've suggested, I still get an error in the console saying `this.model.JSON() is not a function`. What's going on with Backbone?!

Comment: @Shaoz You want to use a single model in the view. For that please do var app = new AppView({ model: AppModel });

Check with this. Now this will work. AppList is a collection, to make it work with the collection you need to loop through each model in collection.

Comment: Sorry, I still get the same error after `var app = new AppView({model: AppModel});`. Here's the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/S3Hsy/... I don't know what to do anymore... :(

Comment: @Shaoz Ah, you are using the model constructor directly. You need to use the instance of the model. Sorry I also didn't see that, I thought you were using the instance. Check the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/S3Hsy/1/

Answer (score 1):

There are some conventions on Backbone that makes it easier to work with.

One of that conventions is that if you pass some specific parameters to constructors, they will be added as an instance property (collection, model...), so you can use them inside other functions.

Please check out the docs, where this is covered really well: http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor